# Using clipboard to paste values from webpage, but VBA paste moves location or errors when range specified

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying a copy paste webpage values: `'wsDMB.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _ False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True`
This line gives a 1004 error only when Range("A1") is included, but would fix my issue of data being paste in different locations if it worked (formulas are countIfing a specific column). Website scraping isn't available.

If performed manually, I would ctrl A copy a webpage, ctrl+shift+v into a data tab, and count-ifs would tally statuses from that data tab's** column C**. I would like a macro button to paste the clipboard contents instead of manually, but unfortunately my code seems to bounce around where the data is pasted in the dump buffer. (I found success with a dump buffer because VBA would clear the clipboard when there is a cells.clear anywhere in the macro). When I specify range A1, I get an error pasting special.

```
Sub Pastewbuffer1()

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsDM1 As Worksheet
Dim wsDMB As Worksheet
Dim pRng As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsDM1 = wb.Sheets("DumpPg1")
Set wsDMB = wb.Sheets("DumpBuffer")


wsDMB.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

'wsDMB.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

wsDM1.Cells.Clear
wsDMB.Cells.Copy

wsDM1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wsDMB.Cells.Clear
Sheets("DumpBuffer").Range("A1").Value = "A1 Good"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```